# ABPersonCopyImageData() on ios8

Tags: objective-c

I have  confused bettween ios 7 and ios 8 about ABPersonCopyImageData.

The following two situations, I have add the pictures to the contact in the system address book.

on ios7,I use the code,it works,I can get the imageData:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{
CFDataRef imagedata = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
if (imagedata) {
    self.imageData = (__bridge NSData*)imagedata;
    CFRelease(imagedata);
}
return Yes;
```

}

But on ios8,as the old method was abandoned, I use the new API,i could't get the imagedata:

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
CFDataRef imagedata = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
if (imagedata) {
    self.imageData = (__bridge NSData*)imagedata;
    CFRelease(imagedata);
}
```

}

Could you help me?
Thank you .